# how do i initialize spring jar and starter file?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, model-view-controller, server

i have a problem when run Spring MVC on Eclipse
[image]

but when i clear the extra path it works properly

[image]

whats the main problem here?

Answer (score 0):

In the first image, I can see that you used HomeController.java in url. You cannot make url in that way. Homepage path need to define in the web.xml file. By default web.xml contain path as project name so your project is working fine with project name in the url path which is absolutely correct. 
However, remember that java never execute .java file. Java execute .class file which is created through compilation of .java file. I hope this will help to understand java better.